# Need help interpreting results of load testing with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I'm relatively new to using JMeter and I'm currently working on load and performance testing to assess the limits of a website. I've managed to set up my tests and generate an HTML report, but I'm facing some difficulties in interpreting the results.

I'm particularly wondering how to determine the optimal number of users to simulate simultaneously, the duration of the test, and the frequency of tests to obtain meaningful data on the site's performance. I've consulted several tutorials and online resources, but I still find the process somewhat unclear.

Additionally, once I've generated the HTML report, I find that it contains a lot of graphs and information, which sometimes makes it difficult to interpret the results.

I would be grateful if someone more experienced in using JMeter could offer some guidance or point me to resources that could help me better understand and leverage the results of my load tests.

Thank you in advance for your valuable help and advice!

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to correlate 3 charts:

- **Active Threads Over Time** - shows the current load (number of virtual users)
- **Transactions per second** - shows the number of requests per second

Ideally these two should be similar, to wit application throughput should increase by the same factor as the load

However in the vast majority of cases at certain point you will notice that despite you increase the load the number of requests per second doesn't increase. That would indicate the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) of your application.

The most common reason for the situation is Response Time which gets increased under the load, it can be observed using **Response times Over Time** chart.

---

With regards to "optimal number of users" - it depends on the [performance testing type](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-vs-load-testing-vs-stress-testing) you're running.

For example if you're doing [Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing) - you should use the **anticipated** number of users from your system under test [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) or [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement)

In case of [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing) there is no upper limit, you should gradually increase the load until response time starts exceeding acceptable thresholds or errors start occurring or application crashes, whatever comes the first.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and for taking the time to help me understand how to interpret the results and the process of load testing. It has provided me with a clear insight into the matter, and I truly appreciate it.

If I understand correctly, we analyze the performance of a URL at the point where we can observe the maximum successful transactions with the shortest response times and the highest number of active users.

Comment: If you could provide more details on the Apdex concept, I grasp the overall idea, but for each URL and each test, I have a tolerance threshold of 500ms and a frustration threshold of 1s. The 500ms threshold remains fixed.

Feel free to add any additional points that I may have overlooked in my question for better understanding.

Comment: It's controllable by `jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold` property, see [Reporting configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting) for available configuration options and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter Properties and ways of setting and overriding them

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter only provides half of the dataset you need, measures of response time.  You need information on what is happening in your finite resource pool - CPU, DISK, RAM, and NETWORK - to understand your limitations.

You can derive some amount of influence my examining the variance of the dataset (standard deviation) of the results that a resource dependency exists.  Using that data you can prioritize what you look at for items to improve.  "Fix" the top 20% of most offensive requests and you will have addressed about 80% of your performance issues - This is a direct application of the Pareto principal to performance engineering.  Take a look at the [ SUM(response times) * StdDev ] for a prioritization of what to fix first.  Your monitors will point to where you need to look on your resource binding.

The value of a performance testing effort is not the data associated with the test results, but a recommendation that results in an improvement in performance (response time/ScalabilityResiliance).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your insights and suggestions. Your explanation regarding the need for additional resource-related data beyond response times in JMeter is very helpful. I appreciate your recommendation to examine the variance of the dataset and prioritize improvements based on the Pareto principle.

Could you please provide further clarification on how to calculate and interpret the result of the [ SUM(response times) * StdDev ] formula for prioritization? Additionally, do you have any recommended resources or guides for delving deeper into these concepts?

Comment: A classical profiler view would be just to sum the response times to find the "heat" in the system, but that doesn't take into account something that is slow but highly efficient (low variance in the dataset).  So, the product of the Cost of the timed event (sum of PASS response times) and standard deviation provides a score to prioritize what to fix first within the current release that is resource bound.  How to get this data? I usually just process the JTL file in Microsoft logparer to output the data I need.  I then leverage the score with code debuggers to look at the requests prioritized